# How to notify parent of a change

Tags: knockout.js

I am using KnockoutJS and I would like to know of a way where a observable object in an observableArray can notify the parent of a change. Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/paragnair/CEEZ5/

HTML:

```
<h1 id="heading"> <text data-bind="text:childrenCount"></text> Fields selected</h1>
<table id="form">
<tbody data-bind="foreach:children">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text:name"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:isSelected"/></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<a href="#" id="btn-add">Add More Fields</a>​
```

Javascript:

```
var Child = function(name) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
    self.isSelected = ko.observable(false);
},
    Parent = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.children = ko.observableArray([
            new Child('One'),
            new Child('Two'),
            new Child('Three')
            ]);
        self.children.subscribe(function(children) {
            header.childrenCount($.map(children, function(a) {                
                return a.isSelected() ? 1 : null;
            }).length);
        });
    },
    header = {
        childrenCount: ko.observable(0)
    };

var parentModel = new Parent(),
    extra = parentModel.children().length;
ko.applyBindings(parentModel, $('#form')[0]);
ko.applyBindings(header, $('#heading')[0]);

function setHeading(childrenCount) {
    header.childrenCount(childrenCount);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn-add').click(function() {
        extra++;
        parentModel.children.push(new Child('Extra ' + extra));
        return false;
    });
});​
```

In the above example, I want to show the heading with the number of fields selected. I have a `subscribe` event for the `observableArray` but that only fires when something is added or removed from the array so when the user actually checks a checkbox in the fields list, the event is not fired. One way of achieving this is by adding a onchange event on the checkbox to call a method on parent which inturn calls some external method which updates the `childrenCount` on the `header` object. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i did not use subscribe but used the `event` on `data-bind` which in turn calls the external function `setHeading`. Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/paragnair/CEEZ5/5/

Answer (score 6):

I think you can approach this in a different way and at the same time remove needless complication. You don't need to separate the models into separate applyBindings calls. In fact it is not recommended to do this unless absolutely necessary as it adds complication and can result in double bindings if you're not careful.

Secondly, if your header is a result of your parentModels children then it really should be part of the same model, OOP principles can and should be applied when writing KO models. This is **the** advantage of choosing to use KO in the first place.

Here is how I would solve your problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/edJyp/

```
var Child = function(name) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
    self.isSelected = ko.observable(false);
},
Parent = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.children = ko.observableArray([
        new Child('One'),
        new Child('Two'),
        new Child('Three')
        ]);

    this.childrenCount = ko.computed(function() {
        var count = 0;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.children(), function (child) {
            if (child.isSelected()) {
                count++;
            }
        });
        return count;
    });

    this.addMore = function () {
        self.children.push(new Child("Extra " + (self.children().length + 1)));
    };
};

var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    this.parentModel = new Parent();  
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Note the ViewModel class is superfluous but I am assuming you have more functionality than is displayed here which would be tagged onto this.

As an aside, why did you feel you need to use a jquery click handler on your button? I see this mistake frequently and was wondering what in the documentation lead you down that path? This can and should be moved onto your viewModel also, which I have done in the example.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately the way things are designed in my application, I have to keep the applyBindings separate. So i need a way to call an external function whenever a value of an obserbale object within an array is updated. And for click handler on button, thats just an example, this is not my actual project.